# Why have a "#" before title with markdown in jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I use jekyll with github-pages and when input "##" i found there is a "#" before the title ,  i don't want it .

How can i hide the "#" ?

It looks like this :
[image]

Comment: Can you provide your source as text. An image is useless for debugging.

Comment: Also, what Jekyll / GitHub Pages theme are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on theme which is used by you.

The `#` symbol is a hash-link that helps us to share link to specific section of you post.

If you don't want to see this, edit the source of your theme, or just change the theme you are using.

Comment: Are you talking about anchor link ? # is not supposed to be visible in the browser.

Comment: Yes, but it's not exactly anchor link. It's a link to this anchor that is decorated to seems like anchor. Just try to click on this link and look at your address bar to make sure.